# Authenticate .net core Web App using Single Sign on while navigating from CRM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, single-sign-on

I have a button on dynamic CRM. On click of this button I need to navigate to a .net core Web App showing the other details. Currently I have implemented AD Authentication and every time it navigates from CRM to web app, it will ask me for login with my AD credentials.

Instead I need to implement Single Signon mechanism where web app is to be automatically authenticated with same credentials I logged into my CRM. (CRM and web app is already under same tenant of Azure Active Directory).

Can someone help me in achieving this or provide me any sample application.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure [prompt=none](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) is appended to your auhorization request URL. E.G:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
&prompt=none
```